How to filter duplicates from `IDXGIFactory.EnumAdapters`?
IDXGIFactory.EnumAdapters seems to be returning the same GPU multiple times with different LUID (at the very least observed this behavior when connected over Remote Desktop).
How can I filter the copies out?
Should I use some other method to retrieve the list of GPUs? I am aware of Win32_VideoController, and it appears to return the correct list, but it does not contain information about the VRAM (AdapterRAM is not it, it returns 4GB for 12GB Titan V).

If LUID is different it means it's seen as another adapter by DXGI. What does this tool tells you https://github.com/microsoft/DxCapsViewer

It shows both original and duplicate. Without going to Direct3D subnodes the difference is in "Graphics Preemption Granularity" and "Compute Preemption Granularity"  are different: duplicates appear to have "DMA Buffer" in both, but real cards seem to vary from card to card.

When a factory is created, it lists all available adapters within the system. Consequently, if there is any modification to the system's adapters, the IDXGIFactory object must be destroyed and reinitialized. Changes in the number of adapters occur when display cards are added or removed, or when a laptop is docked or undocked.
The following code sample illustrates how to list adapters using the EnumAdapters method:
UINT index = 0; 
IDXGIAdapter* currentAdapter; 
std::vector<IDXGIAdapter*> adapterList; 
while(pFactory->EnumAdapters(index, &currentAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) 
{ 
    adapterList.push_back(currentAdapter); 
    ++index; 
}

You can also refer to this page for more help - Solved - How to filter a list of values to remove duplicates
